# C# parallel.foreach freeze

Tags: c#

i have a huge list of file which needed to be read and also checked if the contant contains somthing from another list. This takes a bit of performance so i thought i could run it with a parallel.foreach. Somehow it get stuck from time to time and i cant figuere it out.

```
    Math.Max(2, Environment.ProcessorCount - 2);

            Parallel.ForEach(allPrFiles, allPrFile =>
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(allPrFile))
                {
                    string line;

                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        line = sr.ReadLine(); // 2nd Line
                        if (areaDataCRCs.Contains(line))
                        {
                            Dbg.DebugTxt(allPrFile);
                            areaDataCRCs.Remove(line);

                            if (allPrFile.IndexOf(".prb") > -1)
                            {
                                if (!filesToMove.Contains(allPrFile))
                                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(allPrFile))
                                        filesToMove.Add(allPrFile);
                                line = sr.ReadLine();
                                line = line.Replace("buildingfile", string.Empty);
                                line = line.Replace("dungeonblockfile", string.Empty);
                                line = line.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
                                line = line.Trim();
                                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                                    Dbg.DebugTxt("NO GR2 FILE FOUND - " + allPrFile);
                                else
                                {
                                    if (!gr2Files.Contains(line))
                                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                                            gr2Files.Add(line);
                                    if (!filesToMove.Contains(line))
                                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                                            filesToMove.Add(line);
#if DEBUG
                                    Dbg.DebugTxt(line);
#endif
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                   }

          }

});
```

Did I missed something? Im pretty new to C# so please dont be to hard :)
And also ignore the part of cutting the string. Thats just for test purpose

Comment: Could you please elaborate what exactly did you mean under a `stuck`? If  you press pause in the debugger, in which state the program will be?

Comment: Also please show us the declaration of `gr2Files` and `filesToMove`

Comment: With "stuck" i mean my whole window freezes and I need to close it via VS. 

gr2Files and filesToMove are both just string lists with paths to certain files

Comment: If i press pause the debugger is in another parallel.foreach which I use to move "filesToMove" to another dir.

Comment: And also if I remove the parallel foreach for the "move files" the last state is the parallel foreach i posted

Comment: Dbg is treadsafe ?

Comment: "string lists" most likely are represented with `List<string>` which is not thread-safe for modification. And you modifies them into the loop. Try to replace with thread-safe collections or add locking (not recommended).

Comment: So after i changed list<string> to ConcurrentBag<string> 1 out of 2 parallel.foreach is working. So I added also a thread limit to both "new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }" but somehow it runs 1-3times and then freezes again. any suggestions?